# How to control allowed methods in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've already seen a number of questions on this topic, but none of  the answers seem to solve my issue.

I have the following python modules:

views.py:

```
class MyObjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny] # For testing
    
    @action(methods='POST', detail=True)
    def my_request(self, request, *args, **kwargslf):
        # Do stuff
```

urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'myobject', views.MyObjectViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

When I try to make an actual `POST`-request to the `my_request`-route, I get `Method POST not allowed`.

But as I understand, `ModelViewSet` should allow all methods. Even if I include `http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'put', 'head', 'delete']` in my view, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the exact API url that you are requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`methods` parameter of [action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) should be a list of methods, like this:

```
@action(methods=['POST'], detail=True)
def my_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff
```